# How to send all unsent reports in ACRA

Tags: android, acra

I am using ACRA in my android APP. When my app crashes due to the loss of internet the reports can't be sent. How to make ACRA send those reports when the user will enter the app next time.

Answer (score 1):

ACRA does that by default. Whenever `ACRA.init` is called it tries to send all unsent reports.

Comment: It doesn't do it in my case. I tried to kill my app tried to reload my device. The unset reports will be sent only with the new crash report. I am using acra 4.9.1